# Mirroring a CSS clip path

Tags: css

I'm trying to mirror this ribbon:

[image]

Right now it's a perfect fit for the right-hand side of the product box - not so much the left-hand side. :)

Now, I understand that I oughta somehow invert the entire value, but after messing around for hours I haven't been able to.

```
  --f: 10px; /* control the folded part*/
  --r: 0px; /* control the ribbon shape */
  --t: 10px; /* the top offset */
  
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto auto var(--t) calc(-1.4*var(--f));
  padding: 0 10px var(--f) calc(10px + var(--r));
  clip-path: 
    polygon(0 0,
            100% 0,
            100% calc(100% - var(--f)),
            calc(100% - var(--f)) 100%,
            calc(100% - var(--f)) calc(100% - var(--f)),
            0 calc(100% - var(--f)),
            var(--r) calc(50% - var(--f)/2));
  background: #BD1550;
  box-shadow: 0 calc(-1*var(--f)) 0 inset #0005;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show enough of your "*[mcve]*" code in your question - html and css - that we can reproduce your problem? You've clearly made an attempt, but can you show that attempt?

Comment: Thanks for your response: I've put the entire code snippet there inc. a link to a web page containing the code.

Comment: @JoostBoer Please don't like to outside websites, answerers cannot be expected to screen the safety of every external link, plus, if that link were to become dead at any point in the future, this question will lose any amount of usefulness to the posterity

Comment: Got it Laif, I removed the link.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a `.flipped` style with this rule:

```
transform: scale(-1, 1);
```

Then you read from paragraph to a pseudo-element and flip things back, see below:

```css
p.positioned { /* specificity to avoid using !important in this example */
  top: 0; 
  bottom: auto;
}

.ribbon {
  --f: 10px; /* control the folded part*/
  --r: 0px; /* control the ribbon shape */
  --t: 10px; /* the top offset */
  
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto auto var(--t) calc(-1.4*var(--f));
  padding: 0 10px var(--f) calc(10px + var(--r));
  clip-path: 
    polygon(0 0,
            100% 0,
            100% calc(100% - var(--f)),
            calc(100% - var(--f)) 100%,
            calc(100% - var(--f)) calc(100% - var(--f)),
            0 calc(100% - var(--f)),
            var(--r) calc(50% - var(--f)/2));
  box-shadow: 0 calc(-1*var(--f)) 0 inset #0005;
  color: white; /* Added from your code */
  background: #194abe; /* Added from your code */
}
.flipped {
  transform: scale(-1, 1); /* flips whole ribbon... (1) */
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

.flipped:before {
  content: attr(data-content); /* getting data from atribute data-content */
  display: block; /* this enables transform scale trick. */
  transform: scale(-1, 1); /* (1) ...then flips content back */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="ribbon flipped positioned" data-content="Our Pick"></p> 
</div>
```

(Sorry about my first answer, you can't nest paragraphs, even though HTML inspection on Chrome allowed me to).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution! 

I tried with HTML, but that broke things. It oughta be possible to only alter to CSS and get the intended effect.

So from what I understand, each point has an X and Y value, since it needs to get the left side we have to invert all the X while keeping all the Y so the first value for each point will change and the second one will not.

Somehow the whole value / formulas should be inverted, and some of the 100% oughta be changed to 0%, but I can't wrap my head around which ones.

Comment: In my opinion there's no reason to duplicate the `polygon` css code, mirrored for the left side, with new code, since it will be fuzzier to read than what I've proposed, not to say more code too.